ODBC Driver 18 Heroku Django connection
I have database (Azure SQL) which I need to interact with on my Django backend and also I do have credentials like client id, client secret, tenant id. So basically I'm connecting via Azure App to this database.
I run into a problem when Heroku on its side doesn't have ODBC Driver 18 installed so I followed https://github.com/matt-bertoncello/python-pyodbc-buildpack the buildpack which pre-installs ODBC Driver 17 however I faced another issue with that where my openssl version is 3.0 or something but it requires maximum of 1.1, anyway if this issue is settled I still left with ODBC Driver 17 version which makes impossible to connect via Azure APP credentials, so only ODBC Driver 18 would work for me.
My question is simple, does anyone tried to do the same with heroku and Azure SQL, can you just share steps you take to connect to this database, also are you using VPN for backend? Cuz it seems like proxies can't handle the connection for db as well. Lmao, so many questions asked sorry about that, hope to find the answer here. Stackoverflow seems to be almost empty on that sort of questions, read around 10 posts related to this topic none of them included my problem only the bit of it. Thank you!
